# Two physically different devices on different interfaces with the same IP

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, linux-networking, network-namespace

I have two GoPro cameras that I am trying to connect to simultaneously. They each act as routers, which my two wireless cards connect to. The problem is, they both have IP 10.5.5.9, and I want to be able to run a python script that sends traffic to one, through one interface, and a second instance of the same script to send traffic to the other, through another interface.

Netns would have been ideal, however my wireless cards/drivers do not support it (set netns not in list of supported commands given by iw phy).  I have set up static IP such that each interface has a different address. Each works individually when the other interface is set down using ip link.

I've tried various routing as well, like [this one](http://blog.sebastien.raveau.name/2009/04/per-process-routing.html), and[this one](https://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes), with both resulting in only one interface being accessible.

Is there any way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Why do both systems have the same IP?  Why can't you change one so they each have a unique address?

Comment: Create 2 VM's and give each one access to one of the wireless cards then run NAT on the VM's to let the parent machine get to both.

Comment: The IP is set in the firmware, I cannot change it.